# Oracle 19c: creating a Unique index

Tags: oracle

I am trying to create a Unique index using this SQL

```
ALTER TABLE user_account
    ADD CONSTRAINT uc_user_name UNIQUE (user_name)
/
```

It produces this error:

> ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'USERS'
> 01950. 00000 -  "no privileges on tablespace '%s'"
> *Cause:    User does not have privileges to allocate an extent in the specified tablespace.
> *Action:   Grant the user the appropriate system privileges or grant the userspace resource on the tablespace.

I thought that the Unique index would created in the same tablespace as the Primary Key index for this table; in my case the tablespace name is "portal_data".

I do NOT want indexes (of any type) created in the "users" tablespace; all should be created in the "portal_data" tablespace.

What action should I take?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you don't specify a tablespace, it will use the default tablespace for your user.

You can either change the default tablespace for your user (you should probably do this if you don't ever want to use USERS anyway):

```
alter user my_user default tablespace my_tablespace;
```

Or you can include a [using index clause](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/constraint.html#GUID-1055EA97-BA6F-4764-A15F-1024FD5B6DFE) in your `add constraint`

```
ALTER TABLE user_account ADD CONSTRAINT uc_user_name UNIQUE (user_name) 
USING index TABLESPACE my_tablespace
```

Or you can just create a unique index specifying the tablespace

```
create unique index my_index on user_account  (user_name) tablespace my_tablespace
```